# mod_rewrite conflict

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I am trying to give each MOVIE there own url name, for example, www.helloworld.com/BATMAN.
I have been using mod_rewrite to create such url. I have been using following htaccess code to achieve such result.

```
 RewriteEngine ON
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The mod_rewrite works perfectly.  When A user enters randam movie name (name that does not exist in database), for example, www.helloworld.com/abcd, I have created a url redirect which is www.helloworld.com/oopsmovienotfound.php. This works fine too. But the problem  I am having is this: When user click www.helloworld.com/login.php .The url keeps looping between login.php and oopsmovienotfound.php OR the url is forwarded to www.helloworld.com/oopsmovienotfound.php beacause database doesnot have "login.php" as a movie name. I thought this command

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

should have take care of this but its not. Please help. Following is the rewrite log.

```
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:41 -0500] "GET /movie/batman HTTP/1.1" 200 102262
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/text.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/selectMovie.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/selectMoiveName.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/finalselection.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/categories.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/background.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/tinylogo2.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/header.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/selectState.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/content_tail.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/movieimages/movieimage.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:51:42 -0500] "GET /movie/tab.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jan/2012:15:52:24 -0500] "GET /movie/login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3330
[18/Jan/2012:15:52:24 -0500] "GET /movie/login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3330
[18/Jan/2012:15:52:24 -0500] "GET /movie/img/bg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 102262
[18/Jan/2012:15:52:29 -0500] "GET /movie/img/oops.php HTTP/1.1" 302 102262
[18/Jan/2012:15:52:29 -0500] "GET /movie/img/oops.php HTTP/1.1" 302 102262
[18/Jan/2012:15:52:33 -0500] "GET /movie/img/oops.php HTTP/1.1" 302 102262
```

When I enter the URL `localhost/movie/index.php` the URL is forwarded to `localhost/movie/batman` because `batman` was the movie I was browsing before I closed my previous session. But when I enter `localhost/movie/login.php` the URL keeps looping. Funny thing there is no such folder called "img" in the server. why does it keep looping through `localhost/movie/img/oops.php` when there is no such path?

Comment: "When I enter the URL localhost/movie/index.php the URL is forwarded to localhost/movie/batman because batman was the movie I was browsing before I closed my previous session." =>> How do you do that redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do the opposite first e.g. if it's a file, stop immediately, like this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) -d [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) -f [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) -l
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,L]

# all the other cases, apply rewrite:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Hello Olivier Pons, Thank you for your response, I tried                                                     RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) -d [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) -f [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) -l
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,L]

# all the other cases, apply rewrite:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]  per your suggestion.                                                                  I got error 404 NOT FOUND. I tried without [OR], my url went on a indefinite loop.

Comment: Are you in a hosted environment? If not, then please could you add your rewritelog into your question?.

Comment: Hello Olivier, I have posted the rewritelog into my question. Please help me. I am totally lost.

Comment: How? And if I was right, check, otherwise, answer your own question so that it may help someone else in the same situation =)